# SQL performance improvement by splitting data into two tables (vertical optimization)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I have a table for a system with roughly 500.000 users. The table holds configurations for various servers and whether they accept logins from the user or not.

```
TABLE Config
varchar:SocialSecurityNumber
DateTime:Date
varchar:Server
bool:Open
```

now certain configurations may apply to all users, hence SocialSecurityNumber=*

This means fetching configurations for a specific user is

```
select * from Config 
where SocialSecurityNumber='*' OR SocialSecurityNumber='xxx'
```

Assuming there is little config data that applies to all SSN could I split the data into two tables one containing the SSN=* and the other for specific users. I was hoping thereby that MSSQL would be able to cache large parts of the globaltable

```
select * from Config where SocialSecurityNumber='xxx'
union all
select * from ConfigGlobalSSN
```

what are your experiences with such endeavors? Is union all on tables slow?

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on `SocialSecurityNumber`?  Restructuring the data into tables with the same format would be a last-ditch effort to fix performance, and should probably not be necessary.

Comment: You're not storing actual social security numbers as plain text are you?

Comment: No SSN in DB.. Just an example..

Comment: Last ditch effort? This is a very common pattern called vertical optimisation when moving unused rows away from active rows! This example however I'm separation used rows to help the optimiser.. That was the idea